# 一つの変数に入っている２つの配列から一つを取り出すには？

Tags: php

ある変数の中に何故か２つの配列が入っています。

その変数をvar_dumpすると以下のように出ます。
変数[0]や変数[1]ではアクセスできないのですが、どのようにしたらこれらの配列にアクセスすることができますか？

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "oia" } 
array(6) { ["username"]=> string(3) "oia" ["password"]=> string(64) "5e884898da28047151d0e56f8dc6292773603d0d6aabbdd62a11ef721d1542d8" ["salt"]=> string(51) "»Ñ=¸kÅÌý[GW¢²çô-*Ï£ÂL" ["name"]=> string(7) "oioioio" ["joined"]=> string(19) "2017-04-22 14:06:57" ["group"]=> int(1) }
```

Comment: `array(2) { [0]=>array(1) {...} [1]=>array(6) {...}}` というように外側のarrayがあるわけでもなく、その二行がひとつの `var_dump()` で出力されたのですか？

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/73396

Answer (score 0):

foreachで回しては行けないでしょうか。

```
foreach($変数s as $変数)
{
    var_dump($変数);
}
```

Comment: array_mergeしてforeachで一つずつ取り出す方法ですかね。、